React Native creating app & running it on xcode getting error ReactCodegen
I was creating a normal app in React-Native with the following commands.

npx react-native init sampleApp && cd ios && pod install

When running the app in xcode getting this:

ReactCodegen: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I tried all of these
cd ios
rm .xcode.env.local
rm .xcode.env
pod deintegrate
rm -rf ./build
rm Podfile.lock
cd ..
rm -rf ./node_modules
npm install
cd ios
pod install
open xcode
Product -> Clear all issues
Product -> Clean build folder
click play

In the end, it still did not work.
I installed Ruby
ruby --version
ruby 3.3.6 (2024-11-05 revision 75015d4c1f) [x86_64-darwin23]

also made this

sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup

pod cache clean --all

xcode-select --install

npx react-native start --reset-cache

npm install

But still after all this effort, the error keeps appearing.
Anyone can help me, please?


Did you create the .xcode.env & .xcode.env.local back after deleting them? Setup link

No,how to create them? Also these files don’t exist when creating React native project (npx react-native init SampleApp)

I shared the setup link, in my comment, check it

I already tried it & error still

At this point, there is not enough context to be able to assist. Your best bet, since it's a new project, to just create a new one and copy any logic you set up, if the error persists, then post your app logic to figure out in which part this is happening.

I am currently facing similar issue. I created a new expo app with new architecture react native 0.76 and facing similar error when i opened the project on xcode to build into my iphone

I had this issue when using npx expo run:ios in VSCode or running in Xcode. What worked for me was giving Full Disk Access to Xcode, Visual Studio Code, and Terminal.
You can do this in macOS through System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Full Disk Access

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
